# Php array_filter not accessing array value by Key

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

So The below code works as expected and filters out null values and string "undefined" I was getting in my request

```
$search_params = array_filter(
                    $search_params,
                    function ($val, $key) {
                        return (isset($val) && $val != 'undefined');
                    },
                    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH
                );
```

But when I try to do below the function never returns the filtered array e.g always false is returned

```
$search_params = array_filter(
                    $search_params,
                    function ($val, $key) {
                        return (isset($search_params[$key]) && $val != 'undefined');
                    },
                    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH
                );
```

I was wondering what is causing this behavior, is this some kind of context thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global variable `$search_params` is not in scope inside the function. Use the `use()` directive to indicate variables that should be inherited into the function's scope.

```
$search_params = array_filter(
    $search_params,
    function ($val, $key) use ($search_params) {
        return (isset($search_params[$key]) && $val != 'undefined');
    },
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH
);
```

Comment: Thanks, mate, worked like a charm. I will accept the answer in 7 minutes because God knows what validation :D

Answer (score 1):

Your `$search_params` is not available within the callback function. You must explicitly pass it with `use`

```
$search_params = array_filter(
    $search_params,
    function ($val, $key) use ($search_params) {
        return (isset($search_params[$key]) && $val != 'undefined');
    },
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH
);
```

As of [PHP 7.4](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php) you may use arrow functions, which have access to the above scope:

```
$search_params = array_filter(
    $search_params,
    fn ($val, $key) => isset($search_params[$key]) && $val != 'undefined',
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH
);
```

Read more here:

- **[Variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)**
- **[Anonymous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)**
- **[Arrow functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php)**